# Error con cambio de formato de fechas

Tags: php

Hice un sistema que guarda la fecha en formato `Y-m-d` tanto la de ingreso como la de salida. Lo que hice para dar vuelta ese formato es toma la fecha en una variable y usar `strtotime`, así:

```
<?php
$originalDates = $row['ingreso'];
$originalDates. = $row['salida'];
$salida = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDates));
?>
Ingreso el dia <b><?=$salida;?></b>
Finaliza el dia <b><?=$salida;?></b>
```

Pero error viene cuando concateno la variable para cambiar la fecha de salida y cuando hago esto no me da ningun error, pero nada aparece en la pagina.

Comment: Tienes que hacer cada fecha por un lado, sin concatenar, ya que al concatenar no tiene el formato adecuado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes hacer el cambio de cada fecha de forma independiente:

```
Ingreso el dia <b><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['ingreso']));?></b>
Finaliza el dia <b><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['salida']));?></b>
```

Si concatenas tienes un elemento que es "ingresosalida" y no sabe interpretarlo como dato válido.

Comment: Gracias @Carmen

Answer (score 1):

Mejoré la solución:

```
<?php
$fechaIngreso = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['ingreso']));
$fechaSalida = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['salida']));
?>
Ingreso el día: <b><?=$fechaIngreso;?></b>
Finaliza el día: <b><?=$fechaSalida;?></b>
```

Comment: Gracias @Edgard, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema

Comment: @Edgard está bien la sintaxis, asigna el primer valor y luego concatena el segundo, el primero no requiere concatenación

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error de sintaxis ha un punto de mas en $originalaDates, he probado lo siguiente y funciona perfecto, lo otro seria ver que lleva la variable `$row[]`

```
<?php
$row['ingreso'] = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); // esta es la fecha de ahora
$row['salida'] = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
$originalDates = $row['ingreso'];
$originalDates = $row['salida'];
$salida = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDates));
?>
Ingreso el dia <b><?=$salida;?></b>
Finaliza el dia <b><?=$salida;?></b>
```